# Как добавить свой код/проект на GitHub?

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, github

Всем привет! Я уже два дня не могу добавить свой проект на GitHub.
Работаю я с Java в Inteliji IDEA, сначала пробывал добавить прямо с Inteliji с помощью кнопки "Share with GItHUb", добавил целый проект с кучей ненужной инфы. То есть мне нужно только добавить код и всё. Создать один репрозиторий для всех следующих лабораторных.

Answer (score 2):

Андрiй, сперва настройте файл `.gitignore`, в нем укажите те файлы\папки которые не надо загружать на сервер GIT. Пример файла `.gitignore`:

```
.idea
*iml
conf
domain
target
```

Вам потребуется указать те папки которые вам не нужны на сервере git. Далее, создайте проект на GIT и после загрузите его.

1. `cd /path/to/project`
2. `git init`
3. `git remote add origin git@[your_git_host]:[your_login]/[your_project].git`
4. `git add .`
5. `git commit -m "Initial commit"`
6. `git push -u origin master`

Answer (score 1):

1. При создании нового репозитория на Github поставьте флажок `Add .gitignore` и в строке поиска наберите `Java`.
2. Выберите появившейся пункт `Java`. Github сформирует необходимый шаблон, который позволит не добавлять в репозиторий "кучу ненужной инфы":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Скопируйте файл `.gitignore` в локальный репозиторий.
4. Удалите и заново создайте репозиторий на Github.